# App page not showing - is there a conflict with the javascript?

Tags: facebook

I am having a little trouble pulling some content into facebook

Here is the page that should be pulled into facebook

http://urbanhistoryx.com/facebook

It should be shown here

http://apps.facebook.com/uhx-magazine

if i strip all the code out of the page and write test i can see it, which means that there is something it doesnt like in the page but i cant work out what - any advice please?

Comment: Put bits back in until it fails.

Comment: sorted thanks had to make a few changes but was all down to one line of code lol http://apps.facebook.com/uhx-magazine/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an https connection for this page? If not, then this is your problem.